# There is some known deficiency through the Lebesgue Integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

The Integral in the Riemann sense has a lot of deficiencies, and the Lebesgue Integral can solve almost all of them.

I know that over limited intervals, Lebesgue Integral is a generalization of the Riemann Integral. But
$$\int_a^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx$$
converges in Riemann sense, but it is not true in the Lebesgue sense. So, we could consider this like a deficiency.

But... There is some known deficiency through the Lebesgue Integral over limited intervals?

I read (in wikipedia) that in some cases, the Henstock–Kurzweil Integral is more general than the Lebesgue one. Is it a deficiency? What kind of cases are they talking about?

Comment: If somebody know a textbook where I can find examples and comparisons of the Lebesgue Integral with others integrals, please tell me.

Comment: I haven't read *A Modern Theory of Integration*, but it might be what you're looking for. (http://www.amazon.com/Modern-Integration-Graduate-Studies-Mathematics/dp/0821808451/)

Comment: The most obvious deficiency is that, assuming the axiom of choice, there are still bounded functions on finite intervals that the Lebesgue integral cannot integrate (ie non measurable functions).

Comment: This [comparison at PlanetMath](http://planetmath.org/comparisonbetweenlebesgueandriemannintegration) may be helpful.  See especially the discussion following the article.

Comment: Other than issues of measurability (where in a certain sense there is nothing that can be done), it comes down to these oscillatory integrals (like $\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x} dx$ or $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{x} \sin \left ( \frac{1}{x^3}  \right ) dx$), which converge "conditionally". Like conditionally convergent sums, there is some sense in which we shouldn't say they converge "as sums" at all, because we have the well-known result about rearrangements of conditionally convergent series. You might call this a deficiency anyway.

Comment: @EricStucky I will take a look in the book soon. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @NateEldredge Can you please give me an example? The simplest that you know.

Comment: @hardmath Looks like a part of what I was searching for. It will certainly help me.

Comment: @Ian I never notice that really maybe there are cases like this. Integrals over limited intervals that converges conditionally. This is the what implies the first non-convergence of the first integral in Lebesgue sense. In the second, (i mean $\int_1^{-1}\frac{1}{x}\sin(\frac{1}{x^3})dx$), how can I prove?

Comment: The standard example of a non-measurable function is the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of a [Vitali set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set).

Comment: @NateEldredge Helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @FernandoJunior An easy way to cook up an example: $\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x} dx=\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(1/u)}{u} du$ (per the substitution $u=1/x$).

Comment: @Ian I know how to prove that $\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx$ converge conditionally. But, how can I prove that $\left|\frac{1}{x}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)dx\right|$ is not integrable in Lebesgue sense.

Comment: @FernandoJunior: Simply find a lower bound for the Lebesgue integral. Use intervals that correspond to amplitude of at least say $\frac{1}{2}$ on the $\sin$ curve. You will find that the total measure of rectangles under those parts of your function is infinite.

Comment: @FernandoJunior Another approach is to show that if $\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(1/u)}{u} du$ converged absolutely, then $\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x} dx$ would have to converge absolutely, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L$ the set of all Lebesgue-integrable functions. There are some deficiencies with the class $L$:

(1) There exists improper Riemann integrable functions that aren't inside $L$. For example, the important Dirichlet integral $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx$;

(2) The FTC (Fundamental Theorem of Calculus) version for class $L$ is not too efficient. For example, if $F'(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in[a,b]$, so to write $$F(b)-F(a)=\int_a^bf(x)dx$$ we have to assume that $f$ is limited or that $F$ is absolutely continuous. The Henstock-Kurzweil integral solve this problem definitively;

(3) $L$ is not closed under product of funcitons. For example, let $f(x) = 1/\sqrt{2}$ if $x\in(0,1]$ and $f(0)=0$. So $f\cdot f\notin L$. BUT, if one of the functions is limited, then the product belongs to $L$. However, this deficiency belongs to Lebesgue, Henstock and (I think) any generalization of the Riemann integral that do not require limitation for integration;

(4) This is not a deficiency, but a observation from the pedagogical point of view. The Lebesgue theory evolves high abstraction (needs a measure theory), and generally have none connection with those integrals that we studied in calculus or basic analysis. The Lebesgue-Riesz integral may be a solution at the first contact. But the abstraction is needed to reach all of the power that the Lebesgue integral have to be applied in more general than the euclidean space, etc. Some application require abstraction, so we have to do abstraction.

(Again, apologize the bad English)

Comment: #3 in some sense is a manifestation of the fact that one cannot multiply distributions (in the Schwarz sense of the word "distribution"). In view of this fact, I don't see how you would ever change that without requiring boundedness.

Comment: @Ian I agree. Thanks, Ian, for that help in the other question the I made. =)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might consider a deficiency of the Lebesgue integral is that there are integrable functions whose derivatives are not integrable. For example (taken from Priestley's *Introduction to Integration*) $f(x)=x^2 \sin(x^{-2})$ is integrable on $(0,1]$ (since it extends continuously to $[0,1]$) but its derivative
$$ f'(x) = 2x\sin(x^{-2})-2x^{-1}\cos(x^{-2})$$
is not integrable on $(0,1]$. The first term is integrable, the second isn't because the integral of its absolute value diverges.